# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

I am working with Reactjs. My code is working fine in localhost but whenever I am trying to upload on 'vercel' then I am getting following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

I search and actually `includes` is being used in `routes/index.js` file. Here is our code. Where I am wrong?

```
const Loadable = (Component) => (props) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return ( 
    <Suspense
      fallback={<LoadingScreen isDashboard={pathname.includes("/dashboard")} />}
    >
      <Component {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: just use ```pathname?.includes("/dashboard")}``` as this will render before pathname is available

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Srushti Shah, your issue is pathname being undefined on the initial render. Using the optional chaining (?.) operator will short circuit the expression and evaluate to undefined instead of throwing an error, as mentioned in the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Try updating your code to this:

```
pathname?.includes("/dashboard")
```